# How to called and print "Multidimentional Array function" in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm create the function called Multidimentional Array and I want to print it to the browser. Where do I need to show it ?

This is for a new backend web scripting, running in Apache2, MariaDB 10, PHP 7. In this time, I have tried to add isset function but did'nt work well.

```
<?php

//function Multidimentional Array
function barang (){

$charles = [["nama_barang"=>"Laptop","harga"=>15000,"Qty"=>100,"Kondisi"=>"Baik"],["nama_barang"=>"Dekstop","harga"=>30000,"Qty"=>30,"Kondisi"=>"Buruk"],
["nama_barang"=>"Smartphone","harga"=>40000,"Qty"=>20,"Kondisi"=>"Baik Sekali"]];


}

//Print the result of Multidimentional Array called from function
$oke = barang();

echo $oke;

?>
```

I expect the output is "Laptop",15000, 100, Baik but the actual output is none.

Comment: `echo` expects a string, as your passing an array - you could just use `print_r($oke);`

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question exacly. But according to my understanding you need output like this `"Laptop",15000, 100, Baik`

```
<?php

//function Multidimentional Array
function barang (){

$charles = [["nama_barang"=>"Laptop","harga"=>15000,"Qty"=>100,"Kondisi"=>"Baik"],["nama_barang"=>"Dekstop","harga"=>30000,"Qty"=>30,"Kondisi"=>"Buruk"],
["nama_barang"=>"Smartphone","harga"=>40000,"Qty"=>20,"Kondisi"=>"Baik Sekali"]];

return $charles;
}

//Print the result of Multidimentional Array called from function
echo '"' . barang()[0]['nama_barang'] . '" ,' .
 barang()[0]['harga'] . ' ,' .
 barang()[0]['Qty'] . ' , ' .
 barang()[0]['Kondisi'];

?>
```

Here is the [demo](https://3v4l.org/9jWFg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` to print them on browser

```
$charles = 
[["nama_barang"=>"Laptop","harga"=>15000,"Qty"=>100,"Kondisi"=>"Baik"], 
["nama_barang"=>"Dekstop","harga"=>30000,"Qty"=>30,"Kondisi"=>"Buruk"],
["nama_barang"=>"Smartphone","harga"=>40000,"Qty"=>20,"Kondisi"=>"Baik Sekali"]];

$res = array_map(function($v){
    return implode(',',$v); //echo implode(',',$v)
}, $charles);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```